# Kotlin: Define function for vararg and collection

Tags: kotlin, collections, parameters, variadic-functions

Let's say for examples sake that I wanted to write my own *sum* function, which can take either a collection of ints or vararg ints, like in the following:

```
fun sum(ints: Collection<Int>): Int {
var result = 0
for (i in ints)
    result += i
return result
}

fun sum(vararg ints: Int) = sum(ints.toSet())
```

Is there a better/idiomatic way to define a function for both parameter types? In many cases I only use such functions for one or two element, so wrapping it with *listOf()* outside of the function every time seems clunky to me.

Comment: `Set` only holds unique elements. Do you expect those `vararg` to always contain unique values? If not, the `.toSet()` approach is incorrect.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of that. My bad for including sets, I got mixed up while creating another example, as nobody will want to see my actual code.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no a better way of doing that. You can either use your example or this one:

```
fun sum(ints: Collection<Int>) = sum(*ints.toIntArray())

fun sum(vararg ints: Int): Int {
    var result = 0
    for (i in ints)
        result += i
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better/idiomatic way to define a function for both
> parameter types?

Since both are different types so it's not possible with a function only. You approach is okay.
But you pass an Array as vararg argument using spread operator (*)

Comment: I know, but I don't need a sum. This is like I said just an example.